# IDE other than Eclipse which support Android development

Tags: android

I am currently using **Eclipse 3.5.0** for *Android* development. But I just wanted to try *Android* development in some IDE other than Eclipse.
Firstly, am I going on the right track or is Android development possible only on **Eclipse**? Secondly, if there are options other than eclipse, what are they and in what way are they better or worse than **Eclipse**? How to install *Android SDK* on them? A tutorial for working with that IDE with be really helpful.

Stone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Android development possible only on
>   Eclipse?

No it is possible in other IDE also

- [IntroAndroidDevNetBeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/IntroAndroidDevNetBeans)
- [IntelliJ IDEA 10](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/10/intellij-idea-10-free-ide-for-android-development/)

But the way I understood, **Eclipse is the Best**, because it's plugin and updates are directly given in the [android developer sites](http://developer.android.com/index.html) itself, [ADT](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer the IntelliJ. I was a big fan of Eclipse but when I started using IntelliJ (with some learning curve), I just love it ! The community edition now offers support for Android SDK. However, unfortunately there is no support for building UIs ! So, my solution for now is to configure IntelliJ projects with Android libraries, use Eclipse as a UI builder tool and then use those XML files in INtellJ. I know its a painful process but that is how I get the best of both worlds !